# Is $h(A) := \{h(a) : a \in A\}$ universe of a sub-algebra of B?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A and B be both L-algebras (L is an arbitrary set of operations symbols), and let $h: A \to B$ um homomorphism. Is the set $h(A)$ universe of subalgebra of B?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Without further comment, I will use that by definition every $b \in h(A)$ is of the form $h(a)$ for some $a \in A$. For an operation symbol $\alpha \in L$ we denote by $\alpha^A$ its interpretation in $A$, and similar for $B$.

For each operation symbol $\alpha$ in $L$, we have that
$$
\alpha^B(h(a_1), \ldots, h(a_n)) = h(\alpha^A(a_1, \ldots, a_n)) \in h(A),
$$
so $h(A)$ is closed under all operation symbols in $L$. So all we need to check is that $h(A)$ is actually an $L$-algebra. That is, $h(A)$ satisfies all the equations that the operation symbols in $L$ must satisfy. For an expression $\varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ (using symbols from $L$), we have
$$
h(\varphi^A(a_1, \ldots, a_n)) = \varphi^B(h(a_1), \ldots, h(a_n)).
$$
This should be clear, but if you want to be precise, you can check this by induction on the complexity of $\varphi$. So let $\varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \psi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be an equation that has to hold, an let $h(a_1), \ldots, h(a_n) \in h(A)$ then
$$
\varphi^B(h(a_1), \ldots, h(a_n)) = h(\varphi^A(a_1, \ldots, a_n)) = h(\psi^A(a_1, \ldots, a_n)) = \psi^B(h(a_1), \ldots, h(a_n)),
$$
where the middle equality holds because $A$ is an $L$-algebra, and thus satisfies the equation. So we see that the equation holds in $h(A)$, and so we conclude that $h(A)$ is a subalgebra of $B$.

---

Maybe a small example for what I mean by "equation" would be good. Let $L = \{ e, i, m\}$ be the language with one nullary symbol (a constant) $e$, one unary symbol $i$ and one binary symbol $m$. Then we can write the following equations:

1. $m(a, m(b, c)) = m(m(a, b), c)$,
2. $m(a, i(a)) = e$ and $m(i(a), a) = e$,
3. $m(a, e) = a$ and $m(e, a) = a$.

A set $X$ equipped with the operations from $L$ is then a group precisely when it satisfies the above equations. So in this case our "algebras" would just be groups.